# Redirect in routes.rb with wildcard values instead of params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

To redirect in routes.rb with params we use following syntax.

```
get '/stories/:name', to: redirect('/articles/%{name}', status: 301)
```

If I want to pass the wild card url How can i do it.
I tried the following it is not working.

```
get '/stories/*search', to: redirect('/articles/%{search}', status: 302)

get '/stories/*search', to: redirect("/articles/#{search}", status: 302)
```

I there any hack around for this .

Comment: What will be your `url` and where it will `redirect_to`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one of these 3 solutions should work for you, but it's a little hard to tell exactly what you're after.

This will basically switch out stories with articles and keep the wild card value of the url.  i.e. /stories/hello-world will become /articles/hello-world

`get '/stories/*name', to: redirect('/articles/%{name}', status: 302)`

or if you want to pass the whole `'/stories/*name'` original url

```
get '/stories/*name', to: redirect('/articles/stories/%{name}', status: 302)
```

or if you are wanting to pass the wildcard as a query string you could do it like this

```
get '/stories/*name', to: redirect('/articles/?name=%{name}', status: 302)
```

You can find examples in the documentation. I've combined [3.11](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) and [3.12](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection).